# Issue with lib32asound2

Tags: installation, command-line, sound

I'm complete new to Ubuntu so please pardon my ignorance.

Every time I install something I get the same error at the end. for example...

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove 
Fetched 386 kB in 0s (545 kB/s)       
dpkg: error processing lib32asound2 (--configure):
 package lib32asound2 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lib32asound2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to remove and reinstall this package:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32asound2
```

but with no joy same issue.

How can I resolve?

P.S. I'm running 64bit Ubuntu 12.10 beta 2. Error came after trying to install Skype which failed.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it by typing

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq lib32asound2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try purging it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge lib32asound2
```

And then install it again if you want / need it.

Comment: Tried that too, but i get the error Package is in a very bad inconsistent state. however I have reinstall and get an error too! :(